# How to manually lazy load a module?

Tags: angular

I've tried loading modules without router using [`SystemJsNgModuleLoader`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/SystemJsNgModuleLoader-class.html), but couldn't get it to work:

```
this.loader.load(url).then(console.info);
```

I'm getting `Cannot find module xxx` for whatever string I use for URL (aboslute/relative urls/paths... tried many options). I looked through Router source code and couldn't find anything other then this `SystemJsNgModuleLoader`. I'm not even sure I should be using this...

---

This question was asked just yesterday at `ng-europe 2016` conference - Miško & Matias answered:

> **Miško Hevery:**
>   One just has to *get hold of the module*, from there you can get the hold of component factory and you can dynamically load component factory anywhere you want in the application. This is exactly what the router does internally. So it's quite strait forward for you to do that as well.
>
> **Matias Niemelä**
>   The only special thing to note is that on the [Ng]Module there's something called `entryComponents` and that identifies components that could be lazy loaded - that's the entry into that component set. So when you have modules that are lazy loaded, please put *the stuff* into `entryComponents`.

...but it's not that strait forward without examples and poor docs on the subject (;

Anyone knows how to load modules manually, without using `Route.loadChildren`? How to *get hold of the module* and what exactly is *the stuff* that should go into `entryComponents` (I read [FAQ](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ngmodule-faq.html#!#q-entry-component-defined), but can't try without actually loading module)?

Comment: This link should help you - https://netbasal.com/the-need-for-speed-lazy-load-non-routable-modules-in-angular-30c8f1c33093

Comment: This works for Angular 9+  https://dev.to/mokkapps/manually-lazy-load-modules-and-components-in-angular-1189

Answer (score 62, accepted):

> Anyone knows how to load modules manually, without using
> Route.loadChildren?

You can use `SystemJsNgModuleLoader` to get module's factory:

```typescript
this.loader.load('./src/lazy.module#TestModule').then((factory: NgModuleFactory<any>) => {
  console.log(factory);
});
```

For Angular 8 see [Lazy load module in angular 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56685588/lazy-load-module-in-angular-8/56687548#56687548)

Here is how it can look like:

**lazy.module.ts**

```typescript
@Component({
  selector: 'test',
  template: `I'm lazy module`,
})
export class Test {}

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  declarations: [Test],
  entryComponents: [Test]
})
export class LazyModule {
  static entry = Test;
}
```

**app.ts**

```typescript
import {
  Component, NgModule, ViewContainerRef,
  SystemJsNgModuleLoader, NgModuleFactory,
  Injector} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h2>Test lazy loading module</h2>`,
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(
    private loader: SystemJsNgModuleLoader, 
    private inj: Injector, 
    private vcRef: ViewContainerRef) {}
    
  ngOnInit() {
     this.loader.load('./src/lazy.module#LazyModule')
       .then((moduleFactory: NgModuleFactory<any>) => {
         const moduleRef = moduleFactory.create(this.inj);
         const entryComponent = (<any>moduleFactory.moduleType).entry;
         const compFactory = 
               moduleRef.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(entryComponent);
         this.vcRef.createComponent(compFactory);
      });
  }
} 

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [SystemJsNgModuleLoader],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

```typescript
this.loader.load('./src/test.module#TestModule').then((factory: NgModuleFactory<any>) => {
  console.log(factory);
});
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/pfqTQajIr84mf786rwnG?p=preview)**

There are two options to **precompile** module for **AOT**:

1. Angular CLI lazyModules options (since Angular 6)

---

Use angular/cli build-in feature:

```typescript
{
  "projects": {
    "app": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "options": {
            "lazyModules": [  <====== add here all your lazy modules
              "src/path-to.module"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

See

- @RomainLT **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40293240/how-to-manually-lazy-load-a-module/40293482#answer-52627071)**
- [The Need for Speed: Lazy Load Non-Routable Modules in Angular](https://netbasal.com/the-need-for-speed-lazy-load-non-routable-modules-in-angular-30c8f1c33093) article for more details

2. Using provideRoutes from RouterModule

---

**app.module.ts**

```typescript
providers: [
  SystemJsNgModuleLoader,
  provideRoutes([
     { loadChildren: 'app/lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule' }
  ])
],
```

**app.component.ts**

```typescript
export class AppComponent implements  OnInit {
    title = 'Angular cli Example SystemJsNgModuleLoader.load';

    @ViewChild('container', { read: ViewContainerRef }) container: ViewContainerRef;

    constructor(private loader: SystemJsNgModuleLoader, private inj: Injector) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.loader.load('app/lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule').then((moduleFactory: NgModuleFactory<any>) => {
            const entryComponent = (<any>moduleFactory.moduleType).entry;
            const moduleRef = moduleFactory.create(this.inj);

            const compFactory = moduleRef.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(entryComponent);
            this.container.createComponent(compFactory);
        });
    }
}
```

**[Github repo angular-cli-lazy](https://github.com/alexzuza/angular-cli-lazy)**

---

**Lazy loading with webpack and AOT**

Compilation using ngc

Initialization Compiler by using the following factory

```typescript
export function createJitCompiler () {
    return new JitCompilerFactory([{useDebug: false, useJit: true}]).createCompiler();
}
```

**[Github repo](https://github.com/alexzuza/angular2-build-examples/tree/master/ngc-webpack)**

Comment: Got it to work - it was a bit tricky figuring out the exact path since I'm loading one feature module from another feature module (`src/app/one/one.module` loads `src/app/two/two.module`, and path should be `./two/two.module#TwoModule`)... Figured it out by digging through `SystemJsNgModuleLoader._compiler._ngModule.Scopes[0].Closure.routes.path` which was empty string and not `./app/one` as I expected (: Your plunker example helped. Thanks again!

Comment: Great example and advice! But it seems my dynamic module is not compiled unless I declare it as a route. If I don't include the module as a route, i get error says "can't find module". I'm using ng-cli. Any advice for me? :/

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this without SystemJS?

Comment: @skusunam I added example for angular-cli

Comment: @yurzui thx for that! Concerning the App.module example I had to add a path in the "routes" : { **path: '',** loadChildren: 'app/lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule' }... Seems to work with that.

Comment: @yurzui i have similar problem with SystemJsNgModuleLoader.load, i am getting cannot find module. I am trying to load the module of another webpack umd bundle as loader.load("app2/lib/app2.bundle.js#myModule")

Comment: @Sasxa how do you know the path. I still can handle it. Still getting cannot find module.

Comment: Found solution but I don't know if it is right solution. I had to include a route with lazy load in order for webpack to create the chunk. Which means I need to have accessible route only for this purpose.

Comment: @yurzui - did you ever find a solution. I'm trying to do the same thing with a module generated with ng-packagr with no luck

Comment: Thanks for all the updates. I will try this when I'm ready, and let you know how it goes.

Comment: @swingmicro did you find the solution? Loading module from external url (umd library)?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50149016/load-new-modules-dynamically-in-run-time-with-angular-cli-angular-5/50395048#50395048

Comment: @yurzui
Your solution worked for me. Thank you very much.

BUT, I am also looking at passing inputs and outputs vice-versa between entry component and parent component of the dynamic component, do you have any solution?

Answer (score 10):

**[Angular 6]**

Hello,

I share my solution here because I didn't find how to **lazyload without router** on stackoverflow .

The **Yurzui**'s way works but he uses the Router module to compile the lazy module while I didn't want to use it.

In our `src/angular.json` file we can ask to the **@angular/cli** to compile a module apart.

For that we add the `lazyModules` key in "project" > "your-app-name" > "architect" > "build" > "options".

Like this :

```
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects", 
  "projects": {
    "lazy-load-app": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/lazy-custom-element-app",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "lazyModules": [
              "src/app/lazy-load/lazy-load.module",
              "src/app/another-lazy-load/another-lazy-load.module"
            ]
```

then we can call and load our compiled module.

Like this :

```js
export class LoaderComponent implements OnInit {

      // tag where we gonna inject the lazyload module and his default compononent "entry"
      @ViewChild('container', { read: ViewContainerRef }) viewRef: ViewContainerRef;

      constructor(
        private loader:     NgModuleFactoryLoader,
        private injector:   Injector,
        private moduleRef:  NgModuleRef<any>,) {
      }

      ngOnInit(): void {
       this.loader.load(this.pathModuleTemplate).then((moduleFactory: NgModuleFactory<any>) => {
          // our module had a static property 'entry' that references the component that  want to load by default with the module
          const entryComponent = (<any>moduleFactory.moduleType).entry;
          const moduleRef = moduleFactory.create(this.injector);
          const compFactory = moduleRef.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(entryComponent);
          this.viewRef.createComponent(compFactory);
        });
      }
}
```

source: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/9107f3cc4e66b25721311b5c9272ec00c2dea46f/packages/angular_devkit/build_angular/src/server/schema.json

Hoping it can help someone :)

Comment: nice, can the `this.pathModuleTemplate` be a URL to the module on the server?

Comment: Sorry for the late. I don't think so but I never tried it and I'm clearly not an expert. If you try it, tell me if it works, I'm curious :)

Comment: thanks the module is loaded but the routes inside the module "routing module" do not load and not recognized, how do we load the routes from the lazy module ?

Comment: I think you have to use the forChild method from RouterModule.
https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules 
*Go to "configure the feature module's routes"