# Ng2 load a lazy loaded module on mouseover

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Is it anyhow possible to trigger trigger angular 2 router to preload a lazy loaded module on mouseover and route to it on click to make a large app more responsive?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible.

Based on your configuration, if it's webpack or SystemJS, you can load the module beforehand and then do what ever you want to .

This is the proper answer :

[How to manually lazy load a module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40293240/how-to-manually-lazy-load-a-module)

if you're using webpack , you need to install bundle-loader , and then you can easily require files!.

So for SystemJS :

```
this.loader.load('./src/test.module').then((factory: NgModuleFactory<any>) => {
  console.log(factory);
});
```

And for Webpack

```
let file = require('./src/test.module');

  console.log(file);
```

.

Comment: I think your linked answer refers to systemjs. I have an angular-cli bootstrapped project with Webpack.