# "Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module 'app/lazy/lazy.module'." when using factory to lazy load

Tags: angular, routes, lazy-loading, factory

Using the concept from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40293482/5937695) I have a dynamic angular module loading like this

```
this.loader.load('app/lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule').then((moduleFactory: NgModuleFactory<any>) => {
          const entryComponent = (<any>moduleFactory.moduleType).entry;
          const moduleRef = moduleFactory.create(this.inj);

          const compFactory = moduleRef.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(entryComponent);
          this.container.createComponent(compFactory);
        });
```

I am not using loadChildren, I have the ViewChild, SystemJsNgModuleLoader, and NgModuleFactory all set up which I know because this was successfully loading earlier today. After a restart however, I'm getting the error in the title.

I have tried restarting ng serve with no luck. Why might angular be suddenly unable to locate the lazy module after a restart with barely 15 minutes and no code changes in between?

EDIT: Ok wow, got that working again but have a new question now. I put

```
providers: [
        SystemJsNgModuleLoader,
        provideRoutes([
         { loadChildren: 'app/lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule' }
      ])
]
```

in app.module.ts, which breaks app at the root instead of when it reaches the factory loader (I think because I am using a separate app.routing file and angular doesn't appreciate multiple routes?) but then when I removed this the lazy module was appearing again!

Restarting ng serve drops it again however, so is there somewhere else I can put the provided route that will work with separate routing? Can I ape whatever is being changed when I compile with provideRoutes in the app.module?

Answer (score 0):

Came up with a solution to this, just added an unused route to the root router.

```
{
  path: 'discovery/lazy',
  loadChildren: 'app/lazy-module/lazy.module#LazyModule'
}
```