# Lazy load module in angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a dashboard app where I was lazy loading widgets (not tied to a route).

I was doing this by defining an object `{name: string, loadChildren: string}`.  Then in my `app.module` I would do `provideRoutes(...)`.

This would cause the cli to create a chunk for each widget module.

Then at runtime I would use the `SystemJsModuleLoader` to load that string and get an `NgModuleRef`.

Using that I could create the component from the module and call `createComponent` on the `ViewContainerRef`.

Here is that function:

```js
 loadWidget(
    name: string,
    container: ViewContainerRef,
    widget: Widget
  ): Promise<{ instance: WidgetComponent; personlize?: { comp: any; factory: ComponentFactoryResolver } }> {
    if (this.lazyWidgets.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      return this.loader.load(this.lazyWidgets[name]).then((moduleFactory: NgModuleFactory<any>) => {
        const entryComponent = (<any>moduleFactory.moduleType).entry;
        const moduleRef = moduleFactory.create(this.injector);
        const compFactory = moduleRef.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(entryComponent);

        const comp = container.createComponent(compFactory);
        (<WidgetComponent>comp.instance).widget = widget;
        const personalize = (<any>moduleFactory.moduleType).personalize;
        if (personalize) {
          return {
            instance: <WidgetComponent>comp.instance,
            personlize: {
              comp: personalize,
              factory: moduleRef.componentFactoryResolver,
              injector: moduleRef.injector
            }
          };
        } else {
          return {
            instance: <WidgetComponent>comp.instance
          };
        }
      });
    } else {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        resolve();
      });
    }
```

In angular 8 the `loadChildren` changes to the import function.

Instead of an `NgModuleRef` you get the actual module instance.

I thought I could fix my code by taking that module, compiling it to get the `NgModuleRef` then keeping the rest of the code the same.

It seems that in AOT mode though the compiler does not get bundled.

So I am basically stuck now with an instance of the component I need but no way to add it to the View container.

It requires a component factory resolver which I can't get.

I guess my question is how to take an instance of a component and add it to view container in angular 8.  For now I have reverted to using the string version of loadChildren but that will only work until version 9 comes out.

Here is the version with the compiler that does not work in AOT

```js
 if (this.lazyWidgets.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      return this.lazyWidgets[name]().then((mod: any) => {
        const moduleFactory = this.compiler.compileModuleSync(mod);
        const entryComponent = (<any>moduleFactory.moduleType).entry;
        const moduleRef = moduleFactory.create(this.injector);
        const compFactory = moduleRef.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(entryComponent);

        const comp = container.createComponent(compFactory);
        (<WidgetComponent>comp.instance).widget = widget;
        const personalize = (<any>moduleFactory.moduleType).personalize;
        if (personalize) {
          return {
            instance: <WidgetComponent>comp.instance,
            personlize: {
              comp: personalize,
              factory: moduleRef.componentFactoryResolver,
              injector: moduleRef.injector
            }
          };
        }
```

And here is an example of how I was thinking to do it but then having no way to add it to the `ViewContainerRef`.

The module instance implements an interface that requires an 'entry' property.

This defines the actual component to load:

```js
  if (this.lazyWidgets.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      return this.lazyWidgets[name]().then((mod: any) => {

        const comp = mod.entry;
        (<WidgetComponent>comp.instance).widget = widget;
        const personalize = mod.personalize;
        if (personalize) {
          return {
            instance: <WidgetComponent>comp.instance,
            personlize: {
              comp: personalize,
               factory: null //this no longer works:  moduleRef.componentFactoryResolver,
              // injector: moduleRef.injector
            }
          };
        } else {
          return {
            instance: <WidgetComponent>comp.instance
          };
        }
      });
    }
```

**EDIT:**

I tried to add an example in stackblitz but the compiler is turning my string to functions.  At least the code is more readable.  this is what I was doing in angular 8.  I basically need a way to do this with `import()` instead of magic string.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9yaj4l

Comment: Do you get a runtime error or compile error when building/running with `--aot`?

Comment: When I use the Compiler it is a run time error.  no build time errors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to manually lazy load a module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40293240/how-to-manually-lazy-load-a-module)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In Angular 8 the result of `loadChildren` function is either `Promise` of `NgModule` type in JIT mode or `Promise` of `NgModuleFactory` in AOT mode.

With this in mind you can rewrite your service as follows:

```
import { 
    Injectable, Compiler, Injector, Type, 
    ViewContainerRef, ComponentFactoryResolver,
    NgModuleFactory, Inject 
} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class LazyLoaderService {

  constructor(private injector: Injector,
    private compiler: Compiler,
    @Inject(LAZY_WIDGETS) private lazyWidgets: 
       { [key: string]: () => Promise<NgModuleFactory<any> | Type<any>> }) { }


  async load(name: string, container: ViewContainerRef) {
    const ngModuleOrNgModuleFactory = await this.lazyWidgets[name]();
 
    let moduleFactory;

    if (ngModuleOrNgModuleFactory instanceof NgModuleFactory) {
      // aot mode
      moduleFactory = ngModuleOrNgModuleFactory;
    } else {
      // jit mode
      moduleFactory = await this.compiler.compileModuleAsync(ngModuleOrNgModuleFactory);
    }

    const entryComponent = (<any>moduleFactory.moduleType).entry;
    const moduleRef = moduleFactory.create(this.injector);

    const compFactory = moduleRef.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(entryComponent);

    const comp = container.createComponent(compFactory);
  }   
}
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ifs7sp?file=src/app/lazy-loader.service.ts)**

***Tip:*** Always look at the source code when you're in doubt

- https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/72ecc453639eae017f75653c9004adc406ed2ee6/packages/router/src/router_config_loader.ts#L46-L59
- https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/32886cf9ace539e14e2b387cd8afb10715c8d3de/aio/src/app/custom-elements/elements-loader.ts#L56-L68

Comment: Even in AOT mode this does not come back as a NgModuleFactory. so jit or aot executes the else statement and you get the error about no compiler

Comment: I use this approach in my project and it works well. Can you please provide a minimal reproduction on github?

Comment: well, I created a repo but of course it is coming back as an ngModuleFactory.  so now I will begin the process of comparing build configs

Comment: I found the difference!  In my app I was using a tick mark instead of single quote.  for some reason that makes a difference.  if you use a tick mark to define the path to your module then the cli will not build an ng factory.  this is why I was getting an instance even in AOT.

Comment: I your stackblitz example, what does the provideRoutes in the providers:[] do?  We are not really creating routes right? (I'm new to Angular and am trying to understand DI)

Answer (score 4):

It seems that when using Router, `lazyWidgets` const should have not `name` but `path` property:

```
export const lazyWidgets: { path: string, loadChildren: () => .....
```

Otherwise you'll get error:

> Invalid configuration of route '': routes must have either a path or a
>   matcher specified